# Java FileNotFoundException when using Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, csv, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I have a Java application which runs on an Apache Tomcat server. The Java application is a web service.

From within one of the Java classes I try to access a file, however the following section of code throws a FileNotFoundException.

```
DataModel dm = new FileDataModel(new File("data/WheelChairData.csv"));
```

However if I run this Java application without using the server, I don't get the error message which means that it's apache that's not be able to find it. So where can I store the file WheelChairData.csv so that the server can find it ? is it possible to store it within Apache Tomcat, if so can you please point me in the right direction

Thank you.

Comment: If it's a maven project, just drop the file to src/main/resources. That way it'll end up on the classpath and will be found. You can also tweak Tomcat config to make it aware of additional locations.

Comment: Easiest way is to write the file at location above, and the search for the file.

Comment: How do i tweak the Tomcat config to make it aware of additional locations ?

Comment: catalina.properties - shared loader. Check this https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath#solutions

Comment: I'd recommend checking the app. You want to be sure, that once the app is built your file lands in /WEB-INF/classes in the build directory. If you use maven the full path in your project directory would be (provided 1.0-SNAPSHOT is your project version): target/yourproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/data/WheelChairData.csv

Comment: Thank you for that, i have skim reeded the whole page but its doesnt say how to store the files on the apache tomcat

Comment: See my comment above, check the app. How do you build your project?

Comment: Well the project has just been turned into maven.........which i have built. So were do i go from there... i have read your above message but i am really confused on what to do.. ty for your patience

Comment: No problem. Add the file to this location: /src/main/resources/data/ and rebuild (mvn clean install). Once the build is finished, go and check /target/<yourprojectname-version>/WEB-INF/classes/data/. If you see your file there, it should be found by Tomcat.

Comment: I did all that.... the file is there in that folder... but i still get FileNotFoundExcpetion

Comment: okay, change your code: DataModel dm = new FileDataModel(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/WheelChairData.csv"));

Comment: As @TomasZezula suggests, reference the content from the class path rather than trying to find location in file system.

Comment: if i do that then an error saying that the contructor filedatamodel(InputStream) is undefined

Comment: My bad, you want a file not a stream. But you get the idea, don't you?

Comment: I do want the stream, as FileDataModel requries an inputstream............. By the way thanks for getting me this far.. thanks

Comment: Soz i need the file not stream lol....... but how do i do that

Comment: Tomas Zezula.... i have done everthing i could possibly do.... but i just dont know how to do the last bit... i cant seem to get the file and not inputstream

Answer (score 0):

Use this line and see where the path is:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsoluteFile());
```

(or if you are using logger, put output into it)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It prints out C:\Users\"MY NAME ;)"\Desktop\eclipse\.MyWebService

Comment: You have to run it through tomcat, because it is use case which returns you error...